# Connection string in Database First using EF doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I made a model via EF but when i was trying to execute a query i got this error:

> Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model
>   First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode.
>   To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is specified in the config file of
>   executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from
>   Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional
>   configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then
>   remove the code that throws this exception.

I added model references to my MVC project and i added my connection string to my MVC project but the same error .

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="EducationDBEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.;
     Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa;Password=ehsanakbar"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I get the Exception from this line :

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
```

This is my web config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



      <configuration>
  <configSections>
 <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="EducationDBEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa;Password=ehsanakbar"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: do you have a section for entityFramework defined in your web.config?

Comment: I edited the post .you can see the web.config

Comment: i use db-first.unintentional code first  exc

Comment: Are you sure your DB is running and that your account is working?, e.g. tested your connection with Sql management studio, visual studio or linqpad. Have you tried this guide? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/setting-up-database

Comment: Yes ,the connection string works correctly

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to use a code first style connection string with a model/db first EF conceptual model.

If you EF model has been generated from DB first, you will need to specify the different model aspects in the connection string the `msl`, `ssdl` and `csdl` files.

Your connection string should look like this:
    "metadata=res://*/entityframework.Model1.csdl|res://*/entityframework.Model1.ssdl|res://*/entityframework.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=localhost;User Id=myuserid;password=12345678;database=databasename""

This MSDN article has a good section on what you need from a connection string for model / db first:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674